# Zend XMLRPC API FaultCode 630 Unable to read request Linnworks

Tags: api, xmlrpc

Linnworks is unable to connect to Magento store any longer.

XML can be fetched at `domain.com/api/xmlrpc` but only contains faultcode error 630 (I've stripped index.php from URL's within `.htaccess`).

This was working initially but at some point on Friday this stopped working. It leads to some sort of permissions issue perhaps but no permissions have changed since this working.

I've chowned group and user and made everything writeable on the server but still the same issue. Can find very little similar scenario such as this on the web. Wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction at all to look into this further please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What url do they call?
- What happens when you call the url?
- What looks the request like?
- Is the request in the apache/nginx access log? So it hits the
  webserver?
- Do you have any kind of load balance or varnish FPC in front which
  catches the request?

Comment: Great questions to help with this Fabian. It led me to the resolution. The Linnworks URL is `domain.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc` and we've made some amendments in the `.htaccess` to strip the index.php from URL's (but also 301 redirect to the non index.php versions). Because the `/index.php/api/xmlrpc` redirects to `/api/xmlrpc` and successfully loads the XML file, I never thought it necessary to change the called URL. Sure enough, changing the URL in Linnworks to `/api/xmlrpc` and it connected without issue. Thanks.